# Aggregate count window function

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to make a query that returns rows that have the same name.

For the query

```
SELECT
 version,
 name,
 count (version) OVER (PARTITION BY name)
FROM
 application
WHERE id = 123;
```

I get:

```
 version |         name         | count 
---------+----------------------+-------
 29.0    | Mouser               |     2
 28.0    | Mouser               |     2
 11.0    | Niche Norman         |     1
         | Galaxy Creator       |     0
         | Cube Generator       |     0
```

While the expected result is:

```
 version |         name         | count 
---------+----------------------+-------
 29.0    | Mouser               |     2
 28.0    | Mouser               |     2
```

But when I use `having count > 1` it returns nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use HAVING with Windowed Aggregates:

```
SELECT *
FROM
 (
    SELECT
     version,
     name,
     count (version) OVER (PARTITION BY name) as cnt
    FROM
     application
    WHERE id = 123
 ) as dt
WHERE cnt > 2;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! That worked perfect :)